# What are the benefits of removing solar collectors from a TIE fighter?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-rebels

In the episode, "The Call" of the Star Wars Rebels TV series, there appears for the first time the yellow TIE fighters of the Mining Guild. They also had a notch cut in their stabilizers, giving them eight solar collectors instead of twelve.

Was this really an advantage? These fighters will have less energy and even less protection from what they already have.

Are there any benefits to this design? Better visibility? Better manoeuvrability? Or does it have any improvement over other TIE fighters?

Not to mention the yellow colour, which is very striking ...[image]

Comment: Visibility will be about 10% better

Comment: Moreover these particular tie fighters may be cheaper then their "full" variants..

Comment: There does not seem to be anything inherently flawed though with a swoop and notch panel design - see the TIE Interceptor as an example which is generally considered to be highly effective - http://vignette3.wikia.nocookie.net/starwars/images/6/65/Tieinter2.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20060705184051

Answer (score 12, accepted):

According to the [Databank](http://www.starwars.com/databank), (and as stated by Valorum in the comments), it improved visibility, however greatly hindered combat ability.

> As the Mining Guild was in league with the Empire, its forces were granted certain Imperial weaponry and craft, including TIE fighters. Mining Guild TIE fighters, however, had a distinct yellow color scheme, clearly delineating that they were not in direct service of the Empire. They also had a notch cut in their stabilizers, **allowing for improved visibility, but making them lackluster when it came to combat.**
>   <sub>[StarWars.com - Databank: Mining Guild TIE Fighters](http://www.starwars.com/databank/mining-guild-tie-fighter)</sub>

That's about all there really is on the Mining Guild's TIE fighters

Comment: So, basically like how the US sells war machines to its allies but handicaps them by withholding the most advanced radar, armor, or weapon packages.